# Cand you use a file descriptor if you copy it woth dup2() and the close it?

Tags: linux, pipe, fork, file-descriptor, dup2

So i'm trying to use fork to redirect the output to the file specified  in the command. First I pipe and then i copy the file descriptor of the file given to me in the place of stdout with dup2()  like dup2(output_fd,1)
and then i close output_fd. close(output_fd). Would the process still send the output to that file since I have closed it?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
dup2(output_fd, 1);
```

It makes STDOUT point to the handle pointed by output_fd. So, at this stage there are two ways you can write to the stream pointed by output_fd.

Now when you do

```
close(output_fd);
```

It'll close output_fd but **NOT** STDOUT. So, even if you close output_fd you'll still be able to write to the pipe!